# tcp_tw_reuse and tcp_tw_recycle not working in specific environment

Tags: linux, mysql, linux-networking, tcp, haproxy

We are running HAProxy to direct mysql traffic from PHP to a set of mysql servers. However, due to an issue with the way the mysql-client sends TCP packets, we get a ton of connections in **TIME_WAIT** with **concurrent port utilization at 50k+**, and end up with SOCKERR messages on HAProxy due to port exhaustion under extremely heavy load as described here - http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/12/12/haproxy-high-mysql-request-rate-and-tcp-source-port-exhaustion/

The article above suggests enabling **tcp_tw_reuse** and **tcp_tw_recycle** on the HAProxy server, which we've done on one test environment and this practically solved our issue and kept TIME_WAIT connections below 1000 under heavy load. However, the same cannot be said for another environment we have where we also enabled these two TCP settings - the TIME_WAIT is still high and port utilization is still 50k+.

Both environments are on the same kernel, same haproxy version, and we can't figure out what could be contributing to this specific environment not accepting the **tcp_tw_reuse** and **tcp_tw_recycle** changes.

On both environments, we expanded the port_range to **1024-65535**. This is on CentOS 6.4.

Please assist - we are spinning our heads here and if you need more information, I can provide. Thank you.

Comment: It would seem fairly likely that the changes you think you applied haven't actually been applied.  There's not much else that can go wrong here, absent an extremely obscure kernel bug.

Comment: we are using VMware Vsphere - could the VM host have any deciding control on tcp port reuse by VM Guests?

Comment: No.  <pad><pad><pad>

Answer (score 1):

Found the root cause. tcp_timestamps must be enabled on the local server as well as whatever outbound server you are trying to reach. tcp_tw_reuse and tcp_tw_recycle depend on tcp_timestamps to determine which ports to reuse. See this - http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux.html